# Is there any way to specify IV when using pyspark AES encrypt/decrypt functions?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aes

I'm using pyspark (v3.3.1) UDF function to encrypt/decrypt data.
My UDF function uses python library Crypto, and I can set IV, but I think it will have a speed issue on big data.
So I want to use Spark built-in functions `aes_encrypt`/`aes_decrypt`, but they don't have IV parameter.

Is there any way to encrypt/decrypt data using IV with these built-in functions?
(Or better ways instead of using python UDF function?)

Edit1: To decrypt data I defined a Python function using Crypto library and convert a it to PySpark UDF like below..

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# Converting function to UDF 
convertUDF = udf(lambda z: convertCas...)
```

(Code Ref: https://www.google.com/amp/s/sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/%3famp=1)

Answer (score 1):

The IV is randomly generated during encrypt, as you can see in the [`ExpressionImplUtils.java`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.3/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExpressionImplUtils.java#L75) source code:

```
    :
    if (opmode == Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) {
-->   byte[] iv = new byte[GCM_IV_LEN];
-->   secureRandom.nextBytes(iv);
      GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LEN, iv);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec);
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input, 0, input.length);
      ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + encrypted.length);
      byteBuffer.put(iv);
      byteBuffer.put(encrypted);
      return byteBuffer.array();
    } else { 
    :
```

... which, I believe, follows security best practices. That actually begs another question -- why would you want to be able to specify your own IV?  ;)) Your encrypted data might not be as secure as you think if IV is a static constant.

Comment: Nice spot of IV being used internally.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. :) In my process I have to decrypt data which someone encrypt with IV as the first step. After decrypt it, it doesn't metter to be honest..haha

Comment: Whats your IV length? If it is 12, you may still try `aes_decrypt($col,key,'GCM')`. With some luck (if that "someone" used AES silent agreement to prepend the first encrypted block with initial IV) it might work. Otherwise you're stuck with UDF I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If the functionality you want is not available in Pyspark natively,
the best you can do is use a **PANDAS_UDF** or [vectorised udfs](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) as they are also known,instead of a **Python UDF**. Since Spark 3.x the PANDAS_UDF interface has been [updated and made more usable](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/05/20/new-pandas-udfs-and-python-type-hints-in-the-upcoming-release-of-apache-spark-3-0.html)

Assuming the code you use for encoding and decoding AES is something like

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
import hashlib
import pandas as pd

class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.bs = AES.block_size
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(self._pad(raw.encode())))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return self._unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf-8')

    def _pad(self, s):
        return s + (self.bs - len(s) % self.bs) * bytes(0x01)

    def _unpad(self, s):
        for i in range(1, len(s) - 1):
            if s[-i] != 0:
                break
        i -= 1
        return s[:-i] if i > 0 else s
```

And you define your **Python UDF** like this:

```
aes = AESCipher('01234567890ABCDEF')

# Define Python UDFs
encrypt_udf = udf(aes.encrypt, StringType())
decrypt_udf = udf(aes.decrypt, StringType())
```

And run it like this:

```
df.withColumn('encrypted', encrypt_udf(df['column_name']))
df.withColumn('decrypted', decrypt_udf(df['encrypted_column_name']))
```

You can define your **PANDAS_UDF** function like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
# Define Pandas UDFs
@pandas_udf(StringType())
def encrypt_pandas_udf(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(aes.encrypt)

@pandas_udf(StringType())
def decrypt_pandas_udf(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return s.apply(aes.decrypt)
```

And run it like this:

```
df = df.withColumn('encrypted', encrypt_pandas_udf(df['column_name']))
df.show()

df = df.withColumn('decrypted', decrypt_pandas_udf(df['encrypted']))
df.show()
```

PANDAS_UDFs are quite a deep subject and there are many ways that they can be used but I hope this is a good pointer for starters.

Note : because of the use of IVs (Initilisation Vectors) different results are created even if the plain text and the key are the same

If you are able to share your AES udf in case its wildly different from what I have above then I could perhaps offer more suggestions on how to make it more performant with using the PandasUDFs functionality

Comment: I think the question clearly states _no UDFs_, and definitely _no pandas_udfs_...

Comment: There is also another way I would approach it which would be to create a Scala UDF:  either implementing AES or finding a Scala/Java package that does it and wrap it into a UDF and then registering it with Pyspark and use it. That would be the best as far as performance is concerned but could be quite complex.

Comment: @mazaneicha No. pandas_udf is used in pyspark.Please see the link in the answer about vectorised udfs. I ve been working with big data all the time and pandas_udf is quite scalable. Not the absolute best but still quite good.

Comment: Thank you so much :). I'll check pandas_udf and test it !!