# AES_DECRYPT a MYSQL AES_ENCRYPTed data in pyspark SQL

Tags: mysql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

Data is encrypted in MYSQL with `'`“´`¾´^­-|"ªêãæ'` kind of format.

The MYSQL column definition is

```
Column: mobile
Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
Definition: varchar(16)
```

to decrypt in MYSQL I use `CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(mobile, my_KEY) using utf8 ) as mobile`

Same at pySPARk SQL in a glue job not working.

I tried,

`CAST(AES_DECRYPT(mobile, my_KEY, "ECB", "PKCS") AS STRING) AS mobile`
and error saying `The value of parameter(s) 'expr, key' in the`aes_encrypt`/`aes_decrypt`function is invalid: Detail message: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher` is appearing

Tried other modes as well all resulting in some error.
Also tried to `unhex(mobile)` which gave NULL.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `AES_DECRYPT` expects the iv to be part of the data in the `mobile` column. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76671313/2129801) for some details.